# Cannot hibernate without password

Tags: 20.04, sudo, password, hibernate

In Ubuntu 20.04, I have this config. in /etc/sudoers:

```
...
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
...
```

I've changed it in this way:

```
...
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
david   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl hibernate
...
```

`david` is my user name.
I've tried many variations and searched Internet.
I'm required to enter password whenever I do:

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

With CentOS and other Linux variations it works ok.

**UPDATE 1**:

```
 sudo -ll                                                                                      
Matching Defaults entries for david on hp:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User david may run the following commands:

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    RunAsGroups: ALL
    Commands:
    ALL

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Options: !authenticate
    Commands:
    /bin/systemctl hibernate

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Commands:
    ALL
```

The output for the other system where `NOPASSWD:` works is equivalent.

Comment: You'll probably find that `systemctl` is in `/bin` rather than `/usr/bin`, so you'll need `/bin/systemctl` in the entry.

Comment: `which systemctl` reports `/usr/bin/systemctl`.  But it exists also `/bin/systemctl`.  I've changed to `/bin/systemctl` and it asks still for the password.

Comment: You can try comparing the output of `sudo -ll` on both systems to see if they differ.

Comment: I update with this info... Very useful for diagnosing this command :-)

Comment: It looks like there is a 3rd matching entry after the one you added. When several entries match, the last one is used. Move your entry to the very end.

Comment: Now it works, it was nearly at the end, before this line: `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d`.  If you write an answer, I will select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug sudo use `sudo -ll` to list the flag settings that apply to the user and also all the entries that will be checked against any command for a match.

In the settings, `secure_path=` will show which directories will be searched for the command. This usually includes `/usr/bin` and `/bin`, and your entry would need to use the right directory if it is in only one of them. However, on some systems `/bin` is a symbolic link to `/usr/bin`, so it doesn't matter.

If the command matches several entries, the last one found will be used. This sometimes means that an explicit `NOPASSWD:` entry for a command is ignored because there is a later global `ALL=(ALL) ALL` entry that overrides it. Typically, to avoid this, it is useful to put explicit entries at the end of the sudoers file, or in an individual separate included file.